# Duration - Why do extra work when seconds is negative?

Tags: java, duration

This is the method `toNanos` in class `Duration`

```
public long toNanos() {
    long tempSeconds = seconds;
    long tempNanos = nanos;
    // TODO: Here makes me confused
    if (tempSeconds < 0) {
        // change the seconds and nano value to
        // handle Long.MIN_VALUE case
        tempSeconds = tempSeconds + 1;
        tempNanos = tempNanos - NANOS_PER_SECOND;
    }
    long totalNanos = Math.multiplyExact(tempSeconds, NANOS_PER_SECOND);
    totalNanos = Math.addExact(totalNanos, tempNanos);
    return totalNanos;
}
```

I couldn't understand why need to do extra work when seconds is negative.

Positive numbers' max is `2^63-1` and negative numbers' min is `2^63`, looks like it transfer `-2^63s,-1ns` to `-2^63+1s,1000_000_000-1ns`, but it has to particate in calculate eventually. In my view this is meaningless because `Math.multiplyExact` and `Math.addExact` will throw an Exception when numbers overflow, it doesn't change not matter the judgement existed or not

Comment: Yes, but the adjustment *prevents* the overflow in the case of tempSeconds being equal to `Long.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that before calling this method, the parameter `seconds` and `nanos` must not be overflow. And when calling this method, `seconds` has no overflow danger before calling Math.addExact.

Comment: Very good observation! I have added my thoughts below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra work is needed for the case `Duration.ofNanos(Long.MIN_VALUE)` (and some more cases which result in the same number of seconds).

`Duration.ofNanos(Long.MIN_VALUE)` is stored as seconds=-9223372037 and nanos=145224192.

The simple calculation `seconds*1_000_000_000` would underflow the range of long values (and therefore the naive `Math.multiplyExact(seconds, NANOS_PER_SECOND)` would throw an exception). But `Duration.ofNanos(Long.MIN_VALUE).toNanos()` should not throw an exception, it should return `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

They could have written the condition as `if (tempSeconds <= -9223372037) { ... }` and it would give the same results (i.e. throw for the same values of seconds and nanos) but such a constant is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the way the seconds and nanos are stored internally, **while trying to make the usage of the API intuitive**. You may have noticed this in the `Duration`'s JavaDocs:

> The model is of a directed duration, meaning that the duration may be negative.

You may also have noticed that the class **stores the sign only for the `seconds` field**. So, for a negative duration, the user provides arithmetically logical values using `Duration.ofSeconds( long, int )` and the API "adjusts" the excess seconds and nanos into the corresponding fields.

Examples for negative duration:

- `-1999747475ns` => `Duration.ofSeconds( -2, 252525 )`
- `-2000252525ns` => `Duration.ofSeconds( -2, -252525 )`
- `-252525ns` => `Duration.ofSeconds( 0, -252525 )`
- `-1000252525ns` => `Duration.ofSeconds( 1, -2000252525 )`

The above values are "converted" to the right quantities for the `seconds` and `nanos` fields as per its definition. **That is, `nanos` should be between `0` and `999_999_999`.** At this stage, the field `seconds` may be negative and the field `nanos` will be positive or zero.

Eg, in the case of 2nd example (`-2, -252525`), the values are converted to:
[image]

Now, imagining the computation of `toNanos()` on a number line, the API has to employ the following methods after the above mentioned adjustment:

- "Forward" duration or positive duration is:  **( Number of seconds * NANOS_PER_SECOND ) + nanos**
- "Backward" duration or negative duration is:  **( ( Number of seconds + 1 ) * NANOS_PER_SECOND ) + nanos**

Once again, why "+ 1" in the case of negative? Because `nanos` has been converted to its right positive, reduced value (and the excess added to `seconds`) and travelling on the number line will always be forwards.